# Expose a UI with a Network Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, user-interface, amazon-eks, nlb

I'm trying to install a tool on my eks cluster that includes a pod as UI.

Given how the cluster is configured, I would be comfortable using an NLB to expose the UI via the browser. Is it possible to use an NLB to reach the UI via http? I've read a lot of documentation but it's still not clear to me. Thank you

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

[NLB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/introduction.html) has the primary role of load balancing traffic across multiple target groups, based on the network protocol information (L4 OSI). Compared to an [ALB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html), NLBs are much faster because they don't have to unpack the entire package to reach L7 information.

To your question, a pod that contains a UI component should typically contain a HTTP Web Server that serves HTML+JS content to the browser. HTTP being based on TCP, the traffic should be routed properly by the NLB to the UI pods. I don't see any reason why this should not be the case.